# How do I scrape a specific table if the website has multiple tables?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I recently made a script to scrape some financial data off a website (https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/interest-rates/cleared-otc.html) so I could track changes in trading volumes for a project.

However, they seem to have slightly changed the HTML and my script does not work anymore.

I used to use this to get the values from 'table20'.

```
#Options for Chrome Driver (Selenium)
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\Anaconda\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/interest-rates/cleared-otc.html")

current_page = driver.page_source

#Grab all the information from website HTML

soup = BeautifulSoup(current_page, 'html.parser')
tbl = soup.find("div", {"id": "table20"})
```

However, tbl is now a "NoneType" with nothing in it.

I've also tried the following but to no avail:

```
table_2 = soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name == 'table' and tag.has_attr('id') and tag['id'] == 'table20')
```

So question being, how do I scrape all those currency values for table20?

Answer (score 2):

Well, i see there's no reason to use `selenium` for such case as it's will slow down your task.

The website is loaded with `JavaScript` event which render it's data dynamically once the page loads.

`requests` library will not be able to render `JavaScript` on the fly. so you can use `selenium` or `requests_html`. and indeed there's a lot of modules which can do that.

Now, we do have another option on the table, to track from where the data is rendered. I were able to locate the [XHR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) request which is used to retrieve the data from the `back-end` `API` and render it to the users side.

> You can get the `XHR` request by open [Developer-Tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) and check [Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) and check `XHR/JS` requests made depending of the type of call such as `fetch`

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd


r = requests.get("https://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/xsltTransformer.do?xlstDoc=/XSLT/md/irs_settlement_TOTALS.xsl&url=/md/Clearing/IRS?date=03/20/2020&exchange=XCME")
df = pd.read_html(r.content, header=0)[1][:-1]

df.iloc[:, :5].to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Output: [view-online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/d336a26fba806e4b0b3036cedb8ab00e/data.csv)

Output Sample:

[image]

Comment: @nut_flush easy with changing `date=03/20/2020`, if my answers helps you. feel free to accept it by ticking the check-mark . up-vote as well if you liked.